# Can't create process with current token

Tags: winapi, privileges, createprocess

I want to create a process from my program and inject a dll into the process.

But I keep having these "Access Denied" or "A required privilege is not held by the client." errors.

This is part of my code:

```
HANDLE hCurrentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

HANDLE hCurrentToken;
BOOL tokenResult = OpenProcessToken(hCurrentProcess,
                                    TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
                                    &hCurrentToken);


BOOL result = CreateProcessWithTokenW(hCurrentToken,    // hToken
                            0,                          // dwLogonFlags 
                            processToInjectInto,        // lpApplicationName
                            NULL,                       // lpCommandLine
                            CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,  // dwCreationFlags
                            NULL,                       // lpEnvironment
                            NULL,                       // lpCurrentDirectory
                            &startupInfo,               // lpStartupInfo
                            &processInformation);       // lpProcessInformation


if(!result) {
    cout << GetLastError();
    return 1;
}
```

Can someone tell my what is wrong there? In this case i'm having 1314 error code (A required privilege is not held by the client).

BTW - I'm using windows 7 x64.

**Update**:

The problem was that I was trying to inject from a 32bit to 64bit process.

Comment: You probably don't have the required privileges? The error message tells you everything you need to know. What's the question here?

Comment: Why don't I have privileges? I'm running under administrator privileges and from my understanding the new created process should inherit my token.

Comment: Maybe you need first enable some privileges by using function AdjustTokenPrivileges.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

> The process that calls `CreateProcessWithTokenW` must have the
>   `SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME` privilege. If this function fails with
>   `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD` (1314), use the `CreateProcessAsUser` or
>   `CreateProcessWithLogonW` function instead. Typically, the process that
>   calls `CreateProcessAsUser` must have the `SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME`
>   privilege and may require the `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privilege if
>   the token is not assignable. CreateProcessWithLogonW requires no
>   special privileges, but the specified user account must be allowed to
>   log on interactively. Generally, it is best to use
>   `CreateProcessWithLogonW` to create a process with alternate credentials

Using the token from`OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess())` is also pointless since you could just call the normal `CreateProcess` function...